# CSS - background image to a li item

Tags: css, background-image

All,

I have list items which have a background set to them (RGBA value).

Now I want to add another image using the CSS3 background image property to each list item. For some reason, this image does not show up alongside the list item.

**HTML**:

```
                <div id="c_top_bar">
                <ul>
                                        <li id="c_collar" class="c_tabs"><span>Collar/ Neckline</span></li><li id="c_body" class="c_tabs"><span>Body</span></li><li id="c_sleeve" class="c_tabs"><span>Sleeve</span></li><li id="c_colour" class="c_tabs"><span>Colour</span></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

**And here is the CSS**:

```
    #c_top_bar ul {
    position: relative;
    top: 30px;
    left: 40px;
    width: 650px;
    height: 48px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid rgba(207,207,207,1);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px rgba(207,207,207,0.5);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px rgba(207,207,207,0.5);
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px rgba(207,207,207,0.5);      
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 6px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 6px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 6px;
    border-top-left-radius: 6px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 6px; 
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 6px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 6px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 6px;
    border-top-right-radius: 6px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
}

.c_tabs {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 25%;
    height: 48px;
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: center;
    -moz-text-shadow: 0px 1px 2px rgba(255,255,255,1);
    -webkit-text-shadow: 0px 1px 2px rgba(255,255,255,1);
    text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255,1);
    background-image: url(tick.png);
}

.c_tabs:first-child {
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 6px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 6px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 6px;
    border-top-left-radius: 6px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 6px; 
}   

.c_tabs:last-child {
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 6px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 6px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 6px;
    border-top-right-radius: 6px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
}
```

There is a bit more styling Ive applied to the 'span' tags but ahve omitted the code as its not of much importance.

My question is that when I enter the following CSS to the .c_tabs class (the li items), the image does not show up, firebug reports that it 'failed to load the given url', why?

```
background-image: url(tick.png);
```

Many thanks

Comment: are you sure you're linking to the image correctly? is it in the same directory as the CSS file?

Comment: Thanks Hristo, that was it. I had the wrong path... I spent the whole last night confused why it wasnt working. Cheers,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is working fine at my end on Firefox. Make sure the image is available on the path. The URL defined in the CSS expect the image file to be available in the same folder as that of the CSS file. If you have the image file in a different location, update the URL accordingly.

Comment: Thanks Kangkan. I cant believe I didnt see the problem being with the path. Many thanks,

Comment: Damn... I thought that relative paths in CSS would link as if it's starting from the HTML directory, not CSS directory. Maybe it  has to be with CSS being included as link

Answer (score 0):

You can use some thing like

```
background:url(tick.png) 0 100% repeat-x;
```

instead of `background-image: url(tick.png);`

here I used  repeat-x; to repeat the image in x axis. You can use repeat-y; or no-repeat; too.

Answer (score 0):

Relative path would work like this `background-image:url("../Images/transparent.gif");` while CSS is within a **Stylesheets** folder and both **Stylesheets** and **Images** folders are in the root of same folder